# How to insert Token and data to API and display result

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, laravel-5, token

I am working one one Api where I have to  **Custno** & his **token** which will give me data as output
but I am unable to do so. i have done so for is

```
class Profiles extends Controller
 {
function list()
{
    $data = Http::get('https://hris.kseb.in/osvtest/ksebltws/api.php/usrp/validateConsumerWS')->json();

    
    return view('profiles',['data' =>$data]);   
}
```

**My External Api Is** : hris.kseb.in/osvtest/ksebltws/api.php/usrp/validateConsumerWS

**My beriear Token :** eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJvcnVtYW5ldC5rc2ViLmluIiwiYXVkIjoiYXBpOlwvXC9kZWZhdWx0IiwiaWF0IjoxNjA1NjgzMDUyLCJuYmYiOjE2MDU2ODMwNTQsImV4cCI6MTYwNTc2OTQ1MiwiZGF0YSI6eyJjbGllbnRJZCI6IjMwMTciLCJjbGllbnQiOiJVU1JQIiwib25saW5lQ2hhbm5lbCI6IlVTUlAifX0.3Y2Ns1d8CW9WkoyyU_sblHASJ6NUReBQGLqzlJMTY68

**Custno :** 1146360000000

how can i achieve this ???

when i am hitting req result of **custno** should come

Comment: what is the content-type header for the api request

Answer (score 1):

you can use withToken()

```
 $data = Http::withToken('eyJ0eXAiOi.....')->get('https://hris.kseb.in/osvtest/ksebltws/api.php/usrp/validateConsumerWS',[
    'Custno' => 'your_customer_no'
])->json();
```

For reference of Bearer token, see [bearer-tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#bearer-tokens)

Comment: is is posiible to do so

Comment: it moved ahead but it showing likeArray ( [err_flag] => 9700 [disp_msg] => Invalid Consumer Number )

Comment: check your key name, is it Custno itself, you can set debug to true to debug what is happening, see [Debug](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#guzzle-options)

Comment: I tried code previously with same code atleast array was shown but now it is only showing me blank screen

Comment: update the question to show what you have added so far, it is hard to tell by just words

Comment: function dat(){

     // echo "hello";
     $con = 1145580012185;
     $data = Http::withToken('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJvcnVtYW5ldC5rc2ViLmluIiwiYXVkIjoiYXBpOlwvXC9kZWZhdWx0IiwiaWF0IjoxNjA1NzY1MTIzLCJuYmYiOjE2MDU3NjUxMjUsImV4cCI6MTYwNTg1MTUyMywiZGF0YSI6eyJjbGllbnRJZCI6IjMwMTciLCJjbGllbnQiOiJVU1JQIiwib25saW5lQ2hhbm5lbCI6IlVTUlAifX0.1OgQLIf897xIm4doEUlAXdpw4oehPtFFJ4b0ndtgtpg')->get('https://hris.kseb.in/osvtest/ksebltws/api.php/usrp/validateConsumerWS',
      ['custmoerno' => $con])->json();

        return $data;

Comment: change your $con to string here